# Is there is another way to deal with big numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and trying to solve this [problem on codeforces](https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/219158/problem/G) - which says "Given a number N
. Print the summation of the numbers that is between 1 and N
(inclusive)" - using BigInt as some test cases exceeds over 17 digits and this is my code wiht JS V8 and I am getting a Runtime error

> ReferenceError: BigInt is not defined

```
var n = readline();
n=BigInt(n);
print(((n * ((n)+BigInt(1))) / BigInt(2)).toString());
```

Comment: The linked question says last digit. You surely don't need a bigint to add two single digit numbers.

Comment: @SalmanA I fixed the link.

Comment: When you say "JS V8", are you talking about "ES2017"? Because I believe `BigInt` was introduced in "ES2020". (If so, is there any particular reason you are using an old version?)

Comment: @DBS Probably because: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/79 "JavaScript V8 3.23.0" The platform uses https://v8.dev/docs/d8

Comment: Is there a reason you want to solve this with JavaScript? Have you read "It is not guaranteed that all the problems will have solutions in all the given languages (it's especially about the scripting ones)."?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Just for practice , didn't see that note before

Comment: You could either use a different language or implement the logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik will pass this challenge

Comment: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/77561

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe it states you have to use a BigInt function, just a really big int with over 17 digits.

But the formula is pretty simple.

```js
const input = 10;
const output = (1 + input) * (input / 2)
// output = 55
```

Comment: This doesn't work for input `987654321`.